# Active Directory User From Another Domain Not Restricted by Security Group

Tags: active-directory, rds

We have an Active Directory (on Windows Server 2012) instance which we use to manage access on an Azure RDS deployment.

We have a domain local security group which is tied to an app collection, so the users should only be able to see applications within this collection.
The security group contains two users, one user from the same domain (User 1) and one from a separate domain (User 2) There is a one way trust set up between the two domains.

The problem is that User 2 does not appear to be bound by the restrictions of the security group, when we log in as this user we can see all of the applications. When we log in as User 1 the behavior is as expected, we can only see the applications within the collection.

I can confirm that in AD User 2 does not belong to any other security group.

Is it possible that permissions from User 2's domain are being passed to our domain?